# Convert SQL Datetime in a CSV to local datetime

Tags: sql, csv, datetime

I have an export of all my signal text messages that I've decrypted. One of the stages was the conversion of an SQL database into a CSV, so I now have a large CSV that looks like this:

[image: csv screenshot]

The fields are `_id`    `thread_id` date    `date_sent` `body` if that's not readable.

I want to convert the `date & date_sent` to something like `YYYY-MM-DD` but right now they're in a SQL format like `1568610000000` or `1590550000000`. Is there an easy way to convert these? I searched for about an hour before asking, but most q's are about how to convert a SQL into a CSV not how to manage exported SQL data in a CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have the file stored in Excel (from looking at the 1.59E..). If you can add a few more columns then it's simple to calculate a "proper" date formatted for SQL servers in ISO format.

If your "date" column is D, you can do

`=D1/86400000+DATE(1970,1,1)`  and then format this cell as date (YYYY-mm-dd).

The date number `1,56861E+12` will become `2019-09-16 05:00:00`

Note that the formula is for English Excel, you may have to rename for formula and replace comma with semicolon.

**to calculate without Excel** you can use the algorithms listed on the [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) - your timestamp is Unix Epoch in Miliseconds.

Comment: Thank you! I actually had to make it a custom cell and make that `yyyy-mm-dd [h]:mm:ss` so appreciate it!